# %MACRO TO IMPORT CSV FILES INTO SAS

Tags: csv, import, macros, sas, format

I have hundreds of csv files that I need to import into SAS as .sas7bdat files. I don't want to do it manually as it is time consuming. I'm trying to write a %macro in SAS using a data step but don't know how to specify the correct format and length for each variable. I worry about what if I incorrectly specify the length for one of the variables and then some data won't be read correctly.

Here is an example:

Data_1:

```
A,B,C,D,E
2, Paul Twix, 5/9/2015, 2, 238
2, Paul Twix, 5/10/2015, 3, 238
2, Paul Twix, 5/11/2015, 4, 238
```

Data_2:

```
A,B,C,D,E
2345678, Carolina Ferrera, 5/9/2015, 22, 123
2345678, Carolina Ferrera, 5/10/2015, 23, 123
2345678, Carolina Ferrera, 5/11/2015, 24, 123
```

I thought of running this code first to determine the max length but again I can only check a handful number of files.

```
proc sql noprint ;
 create table varlist as
 select memname,varnum,name,type,length,format,format as informat,label
 from dictionary.columns
 where libname='WORK' and memname='Data_1'
;
quit;
```

When I have a handful number of files, I can manually adjust the length of the character variable, but if I have many files and I specify the format of the variables based on the first file, some variables will be trimmed. Here is an example:

```
%macro import_main(inf,outdat);
DATA &outdat.;

INFILE &inf.
    LRECL=32767 firstobs=2
    TERMSTR=CRLF
    DLM=','
    MISSOVER
    DSD ;

INPUT
    A                : ?? BEST1.
    B                : $CHAR9.
    C                : ?? MMDDYY9.
    D                : ?? BEST1.
    E                : ?? BEST3. ;

FORMAT C YYMMDD10.;

RUN;
%mend import_main;
filename inf1 'C:\SAS_data_1.csv';
filename inf2 'C:\SAS_data_2.csv';


%import_main(inf1, work.SAS_data_1);
%import_main(inf2, work.SAS_data_2);
```

This code correctly displays the values for SAS_data_1 but incorrectly displays the names of the string in SAS_data_2.

Is there anything to avoid this error in %macro?

Thank you.

Comment: All the files have the same format? If so, see this https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/How-do-I-write-a-macro-to-import-multiple-text-files-that-have/ta-p/223627

Comment: All the files have the same format but when I import the files manually, SAS may automatically define the format slightly different.

Comment: Yes, if you use PROC IMPORT that happens. However, if you run PROC IMPORT once you'll see the code in the log. You can take that code, extend the formats and lengths for the character variables as needed (set to200 for now and make it smaller later) and then read it all with the approach in the link.

Comment: Okay. What about numeric variables? What should be the default format so that all digits are read correctly? There are no numbers in the dataset that exceed 10^6.

Comment: Then 8. will be fine for all of those. If you want you can use 16. instead, but 8. should be fine.

Comment: So BEST16. for all numeric variables in case I doubt, correct?

Comment: Not sure what you are doubting.  There is no `BEST` informat, just use `16.`. [Informats by Category](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=leforinforref&docsetTarget=n0verk17pchh4vn1akrrv0b5w3r0.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) > The w.d informat reads numeric values that are located anywhere in the field. Blanks can precede or follow a numeric value with no effect. A minus sign with no separating blank should immediately precede a negative value. The w.d informat reads values with decimal points and values in scientific E notation, and it interprets a single period as a missing value

Comment: Try it and verify your data. If it doesn't work, then make it bigger. Making it default larger means your storage space required is bigger.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help! My code runs now.